# How can I see which Research Agreements are active in Civilization VI?

Tags: civilization-6

In *Civilization VI*, how can I see which Research Agreements I made with which Opponent Civilization?

This is different from *Civilization V*.

Comment: Do you mean alliances?

Comment: No, Research Agreement, in diplomacy you can do that with an opponent to both gain tech boosts for a tech.

Comment: Try looking in the diplomacy menu. Sorry I can't be much help but usually everything you are trading or exchanging with the AI is listed there.

Answer (score -1):

In the top/top left there is a tab called reports. Select that and in there you can see what items you are currently trading out and getting in - under the current deals tab. It's the same place you can see yields, units etc.

(This is what I found out after launching the game and trying a lot of different buttons)

Here is also a [mod](https://forums.civfanatics.com/resources/unit-report-screen.25396/) you could use.

Comment: I don't see the research agreements there...

Comment: I'll check tomorrow night again and change my answer if it doesn't work, I did this a few months ago on another forum, maybe an update changed it or I remember it wrong

Comment: @Flater, Civ VI has research agreements, Civ VI: Rise and Fall has research alliances